# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

After researching I do believe I understand what the `"Segmentation fault"` error is. However, even after commenting out the code line by line, I can not seem to find where the fault is occurring in order to fix it.  Is there something I am overlooking that is causing this error? Below is what shows up when I run the code:

> Ready to play (y/n)? y
>
> 3C AH 4C 3H 4H 2H 5H 2C 5C AC
>
> Here's your cards: 3C AH 4C 3H 4H
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Pasted below is the code that I am referring to. The commented out parts were just me trying to find where the error was occurring:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

vector<string> bigDeck;
vector<string> cardDeck;
vector<string> playerHand;
vector<string> computerhand;
vector<string> shortvec;

const int DEAL_CARDS = 5;


void ResetDeck();
void Shuffle();
void DealACard();
void DealQCard();
void DealBCard();
string CStr(int);
int letsee2;

int main()
{


cout << "Ready to play (y/n)? ";

char yn;
cin >> yn;
if (yn == 'n' || yn != 'y') return 0;

ResetDeck();

srand(time(0));

Shuffle();

for (int f=0; f < 10; f++)
{
        cout << cardDeck[f] << " ";
}


cout << "\n\nHere's your cards: ";
for (int i=0; i < DEAL_CARDS; i++)
{
        DealACard();
        cout << playerHand[i] << " ";
}

cout<<"\n\nHere's the Computer's cards: ";
for (int k=0; k < DEAL_CARDS; k++)
{
        DealBCard();
        cout << computerhand[k] << " ";
}

for (int u=0; u < DEAL_CARDS; u++)
{
        DealQCard();
}

cout<<shortvec.size()<<endl;

cout<<endl<<endl;

//do
//{

for (int woh=0; woh < DEAL_CARDS; woh++)
{
 if ((playerHand[woh][0]=='A') && (computerhand[woh][0]=='A'))
        {
                cout<<"War!"<<endl;


        }
        else if ((playerHand[woh][0]=='A') && (computerhand[woh][0]!='A'))
        {
                cout<<"Player wins"<<endl;
                /*playerHand.push_back(computerhand[woh]);
                computerhand.erase(computerhand.begin()+(woh-1));*/
        }
        else if ((playerHand[woh][0]!='A') && (computerhand[woh][0]=='A'))
        {
                cout<<"Computer Wins"<<endl;
                /*computerhand.push_baci(playerHand[woh]);
                playerHand.erase(playerHand.begin()+(woh-1));*/
        }
        else
        {
                if ((atoi(playerHand[woh].c_str())) > (atoi(computerhand[woh].c_str())))
                {
                        cout<<"Player wins!"<<endl;
                        /*playerHand.push_back(computerhand[woh]);
                        computerhand.erase(computerhand.begin()+(woh-1));*/
                }
                else if ((atoi(playerHand[woh].c_str())) < (atoi(computerhand[woh].c_str())))
                {
                        cout<<"Computer wins!"<<endl;
                        /*computerhand.push_back(playerHand[woh]);
                        playerHand.erase(playerHand.begin()+(woh-1));*/
                }
                else
                {
                        cout<<"War!"<<endl;

                }
        }
/*if (playerHand.size() > computerhand.size())
        shortvec = computerhand;
else
        shortvec = playerHand;

cout<<endl<<endl;
*/
}
/*for (int z=0; z < playerHand.size(); z++)
{
        cout << playerHand[z] << " ";
}

cout<<"\n\nHere's the Computer's cards: ";
for (int y=0; y < computerhand.size(); y++)
{
        cout << computerhand[y] << " ";
}*/

cout<<endl<<endl;
//}
//while(((playerHand.size())!=10) || (computerhand.size())!=10);

return 0;
}
void Shuffle()
{
        random_shuffle(cardDeck.begin(),cardDeck.end());
}

void DealBCard()
{
        computerhand.push_back(cardDeck[0]);
        cardDeck.erase(cardDeck.begin());
}

void DealACard()
{
        playerHand.push_back(cardDeck[0]);
        cardDeck.erase(cardDeck.begin());
}

void DealQCard()
{
        shortvec.push_back(bigDeck[0]);
        bigDeck.erase(bigDeck.begin());
}

string CStr(int n)
{
        stringstream s;
        s << n;
        return s.str();
}

void ResetDeck()
{
        cardDeck.clear();
        playerHand.clear();
        computerhand.clear();

        for (int i=2; i<6; ++i)
        {
                cardDeck.push_back(CStr(i) + "H");
                cardDeck.push_back(CStr(i) + "C");
        }
        cardDeck.push_back("AH");
        cardDeck.push_back("AC");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `std::vector` called `bigDeck` and in `DealQCard` you attempt to access its 0th element, despite the fact it has no elements. Did you mean to put some cards in `bigDeck`?

Comment: yep that was it! thanks so much.  I only had that vector there because I am trying to figure out a way to loop the game the amount of times equal to the smallest vector length (computer length vs player length)... I believe im doing it in a round about way...but thank you! that got rid of the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to access non-existent memory or memory which is being used by other process also causes the Segmentation Fault (core dumped).

*Core dumped* means that the program state has been recorded, i.e, its resources that were in memory and processor.